# MVC Performance Issue with many fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, razor

I have a form that dynamics generates a lot of checkboxes (700+).  The form loads very slowly in IE (but barely loads in chrome), and when I post the form it pretty much locks up my web browser.

How can i debug this or am I doing something wrong that’s causing this performance issue? Or is this expected with a huge form and I should try to split it up.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
    { 
            var model = new TaskRequestViewModel
                {
                    Task = new Task(),
                    Components = db.Component.ToList()
                       …. 
                 }
            return View(model);           
    }
```

To briefly explain my model, I have about 10 components, each component has about 10 sub-components, and each sub- component has about 10 options (checkboxes) available.  Resulting in said 700+ fields (and then a few hidden fields).  It worked OK when there were fewer checkboxes (100ish).

My view is something like this (with 3 nested loops):

```
           @for (int cI = 0; cI < Model.Components.Count; cI++)
           {  
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Components[cI].ComponentId)  

                    @for (int scI = 0; scI < Model.Components[cI].SubComponents.Count; scI++)
                    { 
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Components[cI].SubComponents[scI].Name)                                 
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Components[cI].SubComponents[scI].SubComponentId)

                            @for (int t = 0; t < Model.Components[cI].SubComponents[scI].TaskTypes.Count; t++)
                            {
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Components[cI].SubComponents[scI].TaskTypes[t].SubComponentTaskTypeId)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Components[cI].SubComponents[scI].TaskTypes[t].TaskTypeId)
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Components[cI].SubComponents[scI].TaskTypes[t].Active)
                           } 

                    }

          }
```

Comment: Are you using some client technology like javascript/jQuery to decorate or otherwise control your inputs?

Comment: And there's no possible way to reduce that count or break it up into multiple pages? Or as @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić said, offload as much of that as you can to the client side.

Comment: @Leniency: That was not my first thought, but you are right. I recon that OP maybe uses jQuery decoration of checkboxes, which can be fatal even for page with 50-100 inputs.

Comment: I'd question why anyone would ever give a user the option to change 700 checkboxes at once.  That doesn't seem practical in the first place.  Probably should be broken up into sub forms (other views or ajax).

Comment: No jquery/javascript decoration at all.

Answer (score 6):

Another thing to watch out for is Html.HiddenFor when using client side validation.

When you are using **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js** using the default bundle that ships in MVC project, you will be using a script render like this:

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

(note: you may well have changed the name, this is the default)

When you have this, any Html.HiddenFor will render like this:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The XYZ field is required." name="XYZ" type="hidden" value="">
```

Needless to say, these fields do not need client side validation enabled. The user can't see them, and can't interact with them, and should always be filled by your model.

The way to get around this is easy enough:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.XYZ, new { data_val = "false" })
```

If you do not need client side validation, just make sure the bundle is not included.

More reading on this [here](http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/mvc-hiddenfor-validation-performance/).

Answer (score 5):

If you use the Visual Studio performance analyzers, you'll see by the second level of index accessors your render time starts shooting way up. The HiddenFor, EditorFor, LabelFor, etc. extensions can be pretty intense as they reflect on your model to determine the ID, Name and presence of data annotations while it generates the HTML.

With the render taking so long, the browser tends to freeze as it's started to get some HTML but hasn't gotten it all so it pauses. Even after all the HTML is loaded, any JavaScript libraries that try to run on load will need to evaluate (potentially over many fields - this depends on your business logic, if you're using something like Modernizr, Html5Shi[v|m], etc.) When you submit if you're using unobtrusive validation, you might be getting a freeze as each field is enumerated and checked for validation as well as any OnSubmit type logic.

**To speed up your render:**

When your model uses multiple levels of children, this execution gets really costly with many records. Unfortunately just moving each level to its own Partial View and passing in the parent collection doesn't solve the problem 100%. While it does speed things up, your model names are no longer generated properly.

For example, the Name attribute on an input tag for one of your children would look something like "Components[17].SubComponents[33].TaskTypes[5].SubComponentTaskTypeId" based on your Model having that full chain of context. If you split out to a partial view and specify the model as TaskType, when you try to render the 6th one on the 34th SubComponent on the 18th Component, the name will now be "TaskType.SubComponentTaskTypeId" (assuming your model was TaskType called in a loop) or "TaskType[5].SubComponentTaskTypeId" (assuming your model was an IEnumerable called once).

This means the model binder will no longer know how to turn the submitted form back into a full object.

For us we solved this problem with Editor Templates. These are basically partial views but the context of the parent is stored as a Prefix property that is automatically pre-pended to the field names. It's a bit better performance (still not stellar if you're doing that many fields) and the names will still generate in a way the model binder will understand when posting to your action.

If you use an Editor Template for your properties, you just use

```
@for (int t = 0; t < Model.Components[cI].SubComponents[scI].TaskTypes.Count; t++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TaskType[t])
}
```

If that itself is in an editor template called from SubComponents[n] which itself was an editor template called from Components[m] then you'll maintain the full name resolution. This is because each level will grab the Prefix once and store it while rendering up the children removing the need to reflect your model repeatedly to generate the names.

As a bonus your view because a bit more readable and your display logic is now separated by concern (the data type) rather than mixed together.

**To diagnose freezes on submit:**

You'll need to run some JavaScript performance analyzers to see what's running and when. Look at what libraries are being loaded to see if you need them. If you've got the default MVC reference to Modernizr in your bundle and _layout then you're taking a HUGE hit from that. This part of the debugging is hard to guide since it's dependent on the client libraries being used.

**Edit:** While talking to a coworker who had a situation like this (many rows of 3 levels of children with a textbox, 3 inputs, 3 links and 5 labels per row) he still had trouble with rendering so many records for particular users who had abnormally high rows to report. There was so much data the browser became unstable and occasionally crashed.

He ended up using JavaScript render templates to help solve the problem. Essentially he loaded the parent for each row along with an Expand link. When clicking it, he'd use AJAX to get a JSON object for the children and use render templates to generate the HTML. Of course you have to be careful to set the id and name attributes correctly for the model binder to pick them up on submit but it was much better for him since no 1 parent had so many rows that it caused a problem to render on-demand. Our business logic allowed for it because the checkboxes were basically operating as a chain from a single parent down through its children but not across parents. Meaning it didn't matter if not all the parents were fully loaded when the user tried to do work or submit their changes. This was a workaround because the clients absolutely would not accept paging but also didn't ensure they kept their open records at a reasonable number!

Answer (score 0):

To debug, use the Chrome Developer tools. Then view the network tab and click on 'Preserve records on navigation'. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#network_panel_overview

Once this is done, submit your form and view what is being posted.

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling unobtrusive validation before form submit also works.

```
@onsubmit = "$('form').removeData('validator').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation'); return true;"
```